# Determine which login parameter is incorrect

Tags: magento-1.8, login

I have a strange situation where a client has requested their Magento CE 1.8 store alerts the user to know whether it was the email address, or password that was incorrect when attempting to log in

Currently: [image]

Desired: (if email exists but password incorrect) 'Password incorrect'

**aside from the huge security flaw this presents**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have rewrite the [Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::authenticate()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php#L167-L186) function to do this.

Like

```
public function authenticate($login, $password)
{
    $this->loadByEmail($login);
    if(!$this->hasData()){
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid Email Address'));
    }
    if ($this->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired()) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.'),
            self::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED
        );
    }
    if (!$this->validatePassword($password)) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid password.'));
    }
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_customer_authenticated', array(
       'model'    => $this,
       'password' => $password,
    ));

    return true;
}
```

Refer this for [model rewrite](http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/)